# MultiLabelBinarizer() with inverse_transform()

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, deep-learning, multilabel-classification

I have multilabel labels. Elements in a label means voting. Here is how labels look:

```
array([[ 4,  0,  0,  1,  3,  2,  0,  0],
       [ 6,  0,  1,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 5,  0,  0,  3,  1,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 4,  0,  0,  4,  1,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 9,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 6,  0,  0,  1,  0,  0,  1,  1],
       [ 2,  0,  0,  8,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 10,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0, 10,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 0,  0,  6,  0,  0,  0,  4,  0]])
```

And here is what I tried:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer
mlb = MultiLabelBinarizer()
nn = mlb.fit_transform(labels_train)
nn[:10]
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

And when I tried inverse_transform():

```
zet = mlb.inverse_transform(nn)
zet[:10]
```

out:

```
[(0, 1, 2, 3, 4),
 (0, 1, 6),
 (0, 1, 3, 5),
 (0, 1, 4),
 (0, 1, 9),
 (0, 1, 6),
 (0, 2, 8),
 (0, 10),
 (0, 10),
 (0, 4, 6)]
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is it showing unique values in ascending order?

Comment: This is the expected behavior for `MultiLabelBinarizer`: it transforms from lists of labels to a multi-hot encoding, one column for each label. Your case sounds more like a constrained multi-output regression. Maybe ask how to approach that at stats or datascience SE?

Comment: @BenReiniger, thanks for reply